Converting Lat Long to Forward Sortation Area (FSA)
I would like to know which FSA the coordinate belongs to, is there a way to easily convert the Latitude and Longitude to Forward Sorta Area in Canada? Ideally I would like to do the conversion in Tableau or Python.
Thank you
I have tried to find it everywhere on the intenret but its always from FSA to Latlong which I can already generate from Tableau using the center of the FSA. But I would like to do the reverse of it.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

Sounds like you need to find a list or file which provides the geographical boundaries of each FSA.  I don't believe there is any computational approach which can be used to convert FSA to Lat, long or vice-vesa

Seems like Canadian Post owns the rights to that data... see SO post
